Hibernate logging in code - SpringBoot 2.7.18 and Hibernate 5.6.15
I am trying to turn logging on (and off) within the code. I've done this in the past but have not been able to figure how to do it with Hibernate 5.6.15 and SpringBoot 2.7.18. The following correctly prints out the query string but no parameters at all.
// turn on SQL logging.
((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL")).setLevel(Level.ALL);
((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql")).setLevel(Level.ALL);
try {
    return entityManager.createQuery(query, AmountCommissionHstDto.class)
        .setParameter("contributionType", contributionType)
        .setParameter("stagedPaymentStatus", stagedPaymentStatus)
        .setParameter("distributionExecution", distributionExecution)
        .getSingleResult();
} finally {
    // turn off SQL logging
    ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL")).setLevel(Level.WARN);
    ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql")).setLevel(Level.WARN);
}

